# creating a game on a discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, discord

So I am creating a discord bot and I want it to roll a random number(I already know how to do this) if the roll is higher than 49 the user can use the command "buy". Now that is the part I am not able to code. How to attach a specific command to conditional. Also if the player gets lower than 49 he wont be able to use "buy".

```
if(command === "shekels"){
    var object = (prizes[Math.floor(Math.random()*prizes.length)])
    var shekels = Math.floor(Math.random()*99 +1 )
    message.channel.send(`You rolled ${shekels} shekels !`)
    if(shekels <49){
        message.channel.send("Oi you dont have enough shekels to buy at my store *rubs hands*")
    }//49 brackets
    else{
        message.channel.send("Hey you do have enough shekels to buy something from my store")
    };



};//command bracket



 if(shekels < 49){
            message.channel.send("Oi you dont have enough shekels to buy at my store *rubs hands*");
        }//49 brackets
        else{
            allowedUsers.push(message.author.username);
    };
    if(command === "buy"){
        if(!allowedUsers.includes(message.author.username)){
            return message.channel.send("You did not roll 49 or above so you cannot use this command.");
        }
        else{

            message.channel.send("here " + objectStore);
        };
    };
```

the command above ^ doesnt work for me

Comment: So after the person gets more than 49 he can type another command that allows him to buy something, if he doesn't get it he wont be able to execute the command

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create an array of users globally that can use the command? Preferably using their id. So when they roll above 49, they get added to the array. And then check if they're in when the buy command is used.

```
var allowedUsers = []; //Should be above everything, put it right under your imports (that is, under require("discord.js"))

//Your command handler code

if(command === "shekels"){
    var object = (prizes[Math.floor(Math.random()*prizes.length)])
    var shekels = Math.floor(Math.random()*99 +1 )
    message.channel.send(`You rolled ${shekels} shekels !`)

    if(shekels >= 49){
        allowedUsers.push(message.author.id);
    }
}

if(command === "buy"){
    if(!allowedUsers.includes(message.author.id)){
        return message.channel.send("You did not roll 49 or above so you cannot use this command.");
    }
    else{
        message.channel.send("here " + objectStore);
    };
};
```